# Flask 500/404 errors

Tags: flask, python-requests

I'm experiencing an error with Flask. If I call the @app.route with the function, I retrieve **404 Not Found**:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    return 'Hello!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0", port=10101, debug=False)
```

However, if the function is not mentioned, I retrieve the **500 Internal Server Error**:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    return 'Hello!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0", port=10101, debug=False)
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Maybe enable debug to find out more before asking us?

Comment: Not too much info: "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine. I just copy-pasted your original example and did a curl request to it with:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:10101/webhook
curl -X POST --data "test=true" http://localhost:10101/webhook
```

Both return `Hello!%`

As suggested by @Sebastian Speitel - try enabling debug mode - that will give you an idea of what fails and why:

```
app.run("0.0.0.0", port=10101, debug=True)
```